# Services 3.5 q=system/connect.json 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, services

I have code that use JQuery to call services module and login.
After Login, I call token through ?q=services/session/token and gets the token of the user.
I think that i have got the right token...
After that the code calle to ?q=my_services_endpoint/system/connect.json and pass through the header the token.

the problem is that i get those lines in the console and no success of course...

> 7dR8Eo0pmiTeMCHLUeneAAQFCONn80NgXnJuNqhrtYw login.js:38
>
> OPTIONS http://{localhost}:8888/drupal2/?q=system/connect.json 404 (Not Found)
>   jquery-1.6.4.min.js:4 POST
>
> POST http://{localhost}:8888/drupal2/?q=system/connect.json 404 (Not Found)

this is the code:

```
   $.ajax({
        url: "http://{localhost}:8888/drupal2/?q=test_test/user/login.json",
        type: 'post',
        data: 'username=' + encodeURIComponent(name) + '&password=' + encodeURIComponent(pass),
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('page_login_submit - failed to login');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(XMLHttpRequest));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(textStatus));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(errorThrown));
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $.cookie("sessid", data.sessid);
            $.cookie("session_name", data.sessid);
            // Obtain session token.
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://{localhost}:8888/drupal2/?q=services/session/token",
                type: "get",
                dataType: "text",
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Didn't got the token");
                },
                success: function(token) {
                    console.log($.cookie("sessid"));
                    console.log(token);
                    // Call system connect with session token.
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://{localhost}:8888/drupal2/?q=test_test/system/connect.json',
                        type: "post",
                        dataType: "json",
                        beforeSend: function(request) {
                            request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", token);
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert(errorThrown);
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            alert('Hello user #' + data.user.uid);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

Comment: Please check your API endpoint as handoyo suggests.

Answer (score 1):

what version of drupal did you use?Can you try to remove the q?= and try it again?Also i notice on OPTIONS http://{localhost}:8888/drupal2/?q=system/connect.json 404,it doesn't contain your endpoint.